# Convert a string to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python

I have string as below

```
data="""Country DistrictA PopulationA
Country DistrictB PopulationB
Country DistrictC PopulationC
"""
```

I need CSV output as below.

```
Country DistrictA   DistrictB   DistrictC ---
A       PopulationA PopulationB PopulationC.
```

How can we achive?

Comment: What are those --- and A for?

Comment: Look at io.StringIO to read text data and by specifying the separator as space. Although you have to provide more details and what you have tried. Based on your description it looks like you want to do some transformations too.

Comment: I don't really get how data is formatted and how you expect to transform it in csv, try with a better example and maybe include some code you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

I did not realize how to find "A", but considering we have "A", you can use the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

string = """Country DistrictA PopulationA Country DistrictB PopulationB 
Country DistrictC PopulationC """
string = string.split()

columns = []
values = ["A"]
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if cnt < 2:
        if not string[i] in columns:
            columns.append(string[i])
    else:
        values.append(string[i])
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 3:
        cnt = 0
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(values).reshape(1,-1), columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your question is a bit confusing, but here is a way to convert a string to a pandas data frame and then export it to csv (optional). You can use the `io.StringIO` function to convert your data to an in-memory stream:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data="""Country DistrictA PopulationA
Country DistrictB PopulationB
Country DistrictC PopulationC
"""

file_as_string = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(file_as_string, sep=" ", names=["Country", "District", "Population"])

# optional save to CSV
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This will give you the following output, which differs slightly from your request:

|  | Country | District | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | DistrictA | PopulationA |
| 1 | Country | DistrictB | PopulationB |
| 2 | Country | DistrictC | PopulationC |